# Why is the ResourceDictionary not updating?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to build a multilingual app; so far, the TextBlocks are multilingual, and changing dynamically from one language to another.

Now I am trying to make the MessageBox multilingual, but the resource is not updating and just staying in the default language.

```
TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Sentence}"
// updating with the ResourceDictionary

string messageBoxMessage= 
   (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Sentence");
   // not updating with the ResourceDictionary
```

I expect the `messageBoxMessage` to update just like the `TextBlock`.
But the `messageBoxMessage` value never changes and remains the default value.

Here is the rest of the code. The MessageBox Message is now a property, but it still doesn't update.

`private void CBBEnglish_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("/Resources/Resources.en-US.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        }`

`private void ButtonForMessagebox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxMessage = (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Sentence"); // not updating 
            MessageBox.Show(MessageBoxMessage);
        }`

Comment: How do you do languages switching? I suppose you use `MergedDictionaries`, but it would be better if you show your code.

Comment: What is `messageBoxMessage`? A field? Those are initialized once, better use property with getter which will be executed on each call.

Comment: Why do you need to have a middleman? Have you tried just specifying{DynamicResource Sentence}?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code and now everything is updating correctly.

`var MessageBoxMessage = this.Resources["Sentence"].ToString();`